Сonsole Finance Tracker in Java
I am learning Java and trying to create some projects for practice. One of these projects is a console-based Finance Tracker.
Overview
The main function of the Finance Tracker is to track transactions. Financial tracker identifies transactions by ID. The transactions have a date, sum, and type of transaction. The financial tracker can do the following:

Store transactions (only during the program's runtime)
Input and add transactions
Print the current balance based on the stored transactions
Print stored transactions (by ID, between specific dates, or all at once)
Add transactions from a .csv file to the existing ones or replace all current transactions with them
Save all current transactions to a .csv file (overwriting the existing values in the file)

Review requests
I would really appreciate any feedback on the code: what can be improved, made more efficient, what should have been avoided, etc.
I am particularly interested in hearing opinions on how I handled and used exceptions in the program.
I'd also like to hear your opinion on the logic of storing ID. Should I have stored it in the Transaction class, or is it better to keep it as a key in the FinanceTracker class (as I did)? After all, we don't store transactions outside of FinanceTracker anyway, and the ID is only needed in the context of tracking them. I still have some doubts about this.
Code
Exceptions package
//exception FileCreationException

import java.io.IOException;

public class FileCreationException extends IOException {
    public FileCreationException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

//exception FileFormatException 

public class FileFormatException extends Exception {
    public FileFormatException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

//exception InsufficientFundsException 

public class InsufficientFundsException extends Exception{
    public InsufficientFundsException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

//exception NoTransactionsException 

public class NoTransactionsException extends Exception {
    public NoTransactionsException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

Domain package
//enum TransactionType

public enum TransactionType {
    INCOME,
    EXPENSE
}

//class Transaction

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Transaction {
    private final LocalDateTime dateTime;
    private final BigDecimal sum;
    private final TransactionType type;

    public Transaction(LocalDateTime date, TransactionType type, BigDecimal sum) {
        this.dateTime = date.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
        this.type = type;

        if (sum.compareTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(0)) < 0)
            this.sum = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);
        else
            this.sum = sum;

    }

    public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSum() {
        return sum;
    }

    public TransactionType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public Transaction copyTransaction() {
        return new Transaction(dateTime, type, sum);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  dateTime.toString() + " " + type.name() + " " + sum.toString();
    }
}

//class FinanceTracker

import exceptions.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.time.DateTimeException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FinanceTracker {
    private static int lastFreeID = 0;
    private HashMap<Integer, Transaction> transactions = new HashMap<>();
    public BigDecimal balance = new BigDecimal(0);

    public BigDecimal getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public Transaction getTransactionById(int id) throws NoTransactionsException {
        Transaction transaction = transactions.get(id);

        if (transaction == null)
            throw new NoTransactionsException("No transaction with this ID: " + id);

        return transaction;
    }

    public HashMap<Integer, Transaction> getTransactionsBetweenDates(LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate)
            throws DateTimeException {
        if (startDate.isAfter(endDate))
            throw new DateTimeException("Start date cannot be after end date.");

        HashMap<Integer, Transaction> transactionsMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Transaction> transactionPair : transactions.entrySet()) {
            if (transactionPair.getValue().getDateTime().isAfter(startDate)
                    && transactionPair.getValue().getDateTime().isBefore(endDate))
                transactionsMap.put(transactionPair.getKey(), transactionPair.getValue());
        }

        return transactionsMap;
    }

    public void addTransaction(Transaction transaction) throws InsufficientFundsException {
        if (transaction.getType() == TransactionType.EXPENSE && balance.compareTo(transaction.getSum()) < 0)
            throw new InsufficientFundsException
                    ("Insufficient funds in the balance for the expense transaction of " + transaction.getSum().toString());

        transactions.put(lastFreeID, transaction);
        lastFreeID++;

        if (transaction.getType() == TransactionType.INCOME)
            balance = balance.add(transaction.getSum());
        else
            balance = balance.subtract(transaction.getSum());
    }

    public void addTransactionsFromFile(Path filePath) throws FileFormatException, FileNotFoundException {
        ensureFileIsExistAndReadable(filePath);
        ensureFileHasCorrectType(filePath);
        ensureFileHasCorrectNumberOfValuesInLines(filePath);

        HashMap<Integer, Transaction> transactionsCopy = copyTransactions();
        int copyOfLastFreeId = lastFreeID;

        safelyAddTransactionsFromFile(filePath, transactionsCopy, copyOfLastFreeId);
    }

    public void replaceTransactionsWithFileTransactions(Path filePath) throws FileFormatException, FileNotFoundException {
        ensureFileIsExistAndReadable(filePath);
        ensureFileHasCorrectType(filePath);
        ensureFileHasCorrectNumberOfValuesInLines(filePath);

        HashMap<Integer, Transaction> transactionsCopy = copyTransactions();
        int copyOfLastFreeId = lastFreeID;
        transactions.clear();
        lastFreeID = 0;

        safelyAddTransactionsFromFile(filePath, transactionsCopy, copyOfLastFreeId);
    }

    private void ensureFileIsExistAndReadable(Path filePath) throws FileFormatException, FileNotFoundException {
        if (!Files.exists(filePath))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File doesn't exist: " + filePath);

        if (!Files.isReadable(filePath)) {
            throw new FileFormatException("File isn't readable: " + filePath);
        }
    }

    private void ensureFileHasCorrectType(Path filePath) throws FileFormatException {
        if (!filePath.toString().endsWith(".csv"))
            throw new FileFormatException("Incorrect file type! It should be CSV: " + filePath);
    }

    private void ensureFileHasCorrectNumberOfValuesInLines(Path filePath) throws FileFormatException {
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(filePath)) {
            if (!lines.allMatch(line -> line.contains(",") || line.split(",").length == 3))
                throw new FileFormatException("Lines in the file must contains 3 values each!");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected IO exception during file processing", e);
        }
    }

    private HashMap<Integer, Transaction> copyTransactions() {
        HashMap<Integer, Transaction> transactionsCopy = new HashMap<>();

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Transaction> transactionPair : transactions.entrySet())
            transactionsCopy.put(transactionPair.getKey(), transactionPair.getValue().copyTransaction());

        return transactionsCopy;
    }

    private void safelyAddTransactionsFromFile
            (Path filePath, HashMap<Integer, Transaction> transactionsCopy, Integer copyOfLastFreeId)
            throws FileFormatException {
        String line;
        int lineNumber = 0;
        try (BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath.toString()))) {
            while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] transactionLineArray = line.split(",");
                LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(transactionLineArray[0]);
                TransactionType type = TransactionType.valueOf(transactionLineArray[1]);
                BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(transactionLineArray[2]);

                addTransaction(new Transaction(dateTime, type, sum));

                lineNumber++;
            }
        } catch (InsufficientFundsException | RuntimeException e) {
            transactions = transactionsCopy;
            lastFreeID = copyOfLastFreeId;
            throw new FileFormatException("Incorrect values in the file lines. No transactions were added." +
                    "The exception occurred on line " + lineNumber);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //it shouldn't happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected IO exception during file processing", e);
        }
    }

    public void saveTransactionsToFile(Path filePath)
            throws NoTransactionsException, FileNotFoundException, FileFormatException, FileCreationException {
        if (transactions.isEmpty())
            throw new NoTransactionsException("No transactions to save.");

        ensureFileCanBeCreated(filePath);
        createFileIfNotExists(filePath);
        ensureFileIsExistsAndWritable(filePath);
        ensureFileHasCorrectType(filePath);

        try (PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath.toString())))) {
            for (Transaction transaction : transactions.values()) {
                String stringOfValues = transaction.toString().replace(" ", ",");
                printWriter.println(stringOfValues);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //it shouldn't happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected IO exception during file processing", e);
        }
    }

    private void ensureFileCanBeCreated(Path filePath) throws FileCreationException {
        try {
            Path tempFilePath = Files.createTempFile(filePath.getParent(), "temp", ".csv");
            File tempFile = new File(tempFilePath.toUri());
            tempFile.delete();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new FileCreationException("File can't be created: " + filePath);
        }
    }

    private void createFileIfNotExists(Path filePath) throws FileCreationException {
        try {
            if (Files.notExists(filePath)) {
                Files.createFile(filePath);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new FileCreationException("Unknown I/O exception occurred during file or directory creation: "
                    + filePath);
        }
    }

    public void ensureFileIsExistsAndWritable(Path filePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
        if (!Files.exists(filePath))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File doesn't exist: " + filePath);

        if (!Files.isWritable(filePath))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File isn't writable: " + filePath);
    }
}

UI package
//class FinanceTrackerUserInterface

import domain.*;
import exceptions.*;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.nio.file.InvalidPathException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.DateTimeException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FinanceTrackerUserInterface {
    private final FinanceTracker financeTracker  = new FinanceTracker();
    private final Scanner scanner;

    public FinanceTrackerUserInterface(Scanner scanner) {
        this.scanner = scanner;
    }

    public void start() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("List of commands:");
            System.out.println("1 - Add transaction");
            System.out.println("2 - Print all transactions");
            System.out.println("3 - Print transaction by id");
            System.out.println("4 - Print transactions between dates");
            System.out.println("5 - Print balance");
            System.out.println("6 - Add transactions from file");
            System.out.println("7 - Replace the current transactions with transactions form the file");
            System.out.println("8 - Save the current transactions to file");
            System.out.println("q - Quit");
            System.out.print("> ");
            String command = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println();

            try {
                if (command.equals("1")) {
                    enterAndAddTransaction();
                } else if (command.equals("2")) {
                    printAllTransactions();
                } else if (command.equals("3")) {
                    printTransactionById();
                } else if (command.equals("4")) {
                    printTransactionsBetweenDates();
                } else if (command.equals("5")) {
                    printBalance();
                } else if (command.equals("6")) {
                    addTransactionsFromFile();
                } else if (command.equals("7")) {
                    replaceCurrentTransactionsWithFile();
                } else if (command.equals("8")) {
                    saveCurrentTransactionsToFile();
                } else if (command.equals("q")) {
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | DateTimeException | FileFormatException | FileNotFoundException |
                     FileCreationException | InsufficientFundsException | NoTransactionsException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private void enterAndAddTransaction() throws IllegalArgumentException, InsufficientFundsException {
        System.out.println("Enter the transaction type (INCOME/EXPENSE)");
        String transactionTypeString = scanner.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("Enter the sum of transaction");
        String sumString = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        try {
            TransactionType transactionType = TransactionType.valueOf(transactionTypeString);
            BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(sumString);

            financeTracker.addTransaction(new Transaction(LocalDateTime.now(), transactionType, sum));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect transaction sum: " + sumString);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect transaction type: " + transactionTypeString);
        }
    }

    private void printAllTransactions() throws NoTransactionsException {
        HashMap<Integer, Transaction> transactionsMap =
                financeTracker.getTransactionsBetweenDates(LocalDateTime.MIN, LocalDateTime.MAX);

        if (transactionsMap.isEmpty())
            throw new NoTransactionsException("No transactions have been added yet.");

        transactionsMap.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " " + value));
    }

    private void printTransactionById() throws IllegalArgumentException, NoTransactionsException {
        System.out.println("Enter the transaction ID");
        String idString = scanner.nextLine();
        try {
            int id = Integer.parseInt(idString);

            System.out.println(id + " " + financeTracker.getTransactionById(id));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect ID: " + idString);
        }
    }

    private void printTransactionsBetweenDates() throws DateTimeException, NoTransactionsException {

        System.out.println("Enter the start date in the following format: yyyy-mm-dd");
        LocalDateTime startDate = enterTheDate();
        System.out.println("Enter the end date in the following format: yyyy-mm-dd");
        LocalDateTime endDate = enterTheDate();

        HashMap<Integer, Transaction> transactionsMap =
                financeTracker.getTransactionsBetweenDates(startDate, endDate);

        if (transactionsMap.isEmpty())
            throw new NoTransactionsException("No transactions between these dates.");

        System.out.println();

        transactionsMap.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " " + value));
    }

    private LocalDateTime enterTheDate() throws DateTimeException {
        String[] endDateTimeStrings = scanner.nextLine().split("-");
        try {
            int[] endDateTimeNumbers = Arrays.stream(endDateTimeStrings).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
            return LocalDateTime.of(endDateTimeNumbers[0], endDateTimeNumbers[1], endDateTimeNumbers[2], 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (DateTimeException | NumberFormatException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            throw new DateTimeException("Incorrect date format: " + String.join("-", endDateTimeStrings));
        }
    }

    private void printBalance() {
        System.out.println(financeTracker.getBalance());
    }

    private void addTransactionsFromFile() throws InvalidPathException, FileFormatException, FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Enter the file absolute path. " +
                "The file must be a CSV file, and all lines should be formatted as date,type,sum");
        Path filePath = enterFilePath();

        financeTracker.addTransactionsFromFile(filePath);
    }

    private void replaceCurrentTransactionsWithFile()
            throws InvalidPathException, FileFormatException, FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Enter the file absolute path. " +
                "The file must be a CSV file, and all lines should be formatted as date,type,sum");
        Path filePath = enterFilePath();

        financeTracker.replaceTransactionsWithFileTransactions(filePath);
    }

    private void saveCurrentTransactionsToFile()
            throws NoTransactionsException, FileFormatException, FileCreationException, FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Enter the file absolute path. " +
                "File will be created, if it doesn't exist, but it must be created in an existing directory.");
        Path filePath = enterFilePath();

        financeTracker.saveTransactionsToFile(filePath);
    }

    private Path enterFilePath() throws InvalidPathException {
        String filePathString = scanner.nextLine();
        Path filePath;
        try {
            filePath = Paths.get(filePathString);
        } catch (InvalidPathException e) {
            throw new InvalidPathException(filePathString, "Incorrect path format.");
        }

        if (!filePath.isAbsolute())
            throw new InvalidPathException(filePathString, "The path must be absolute.");

        return filePath;
    }
}


Main class
//class Program

import ui.FinanceTrackerUserInterface;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        FinanceTrackerUserInterface ui = new FinanceTrackerUserInterface(scanner);

        ui.start();
    }
}



Your code is quite good for a beginner. Do you maybe have experience from some other language already?
The FinanceTracker class is a bit of a swiss army knife. It attempts to implement every single feature your application has. This is a violation of the single responsibility principle. The FinanceTracker should be split into several different classes.
You need a TransactionStorage that provides CRUD-operations for storing transactions. The search methods might be combined into one using TransactionSearchCriteria as the parameter type. Come to think of it, this could be an interface with different implementations that either store transactions in memory, database or read/write them to a file, because then writing transactions to a file (I bet anyone using a finance tracker would want CSV support) could be implemented by reading transactions from one storage and writing them into another.
The responsibility of moving transactions from one storage to another would be the responsibility of another dedicated class. You wouldn't be limited to just copying the whole storage to another. You could, for example, copy just the results of a single search. Implementing a feature for "write last month's expenses to a CSV" would become a trivial feature then.
The Transaction should be a record. It guarantees immutability and communicates it clearly to whoever will read the code next. No need for checking whether you have implemented it correctly (because you forgot the final qualifier from the class itself and now a subclass can break the immutability promise).
I'm not convinced that a finance tracker should keep track of the balance as a separate field of information. If there is a need for balance, it is something that should be calculated on demand from the debit and credit transactions (e.g. monthly or yearly balance).
As for application architecture, a common three-tier architecture would work for you. On one layer you have the storage layer, which is the TransactionStorage. On the second layer you have domain services, which implement the functions of the application. The class that copies transactions from storage to another would be on this layer. And on the third layer is the user interface.

It's good that you've added packages - but those packages should not be at the top level. Instead, your top-level package should be in reverse domain notation; in my example code I've used com.stackexchange.cr293342.
Avoid import *, especially from large system packages. The only instance where I found that it's still called-for in your code is import exceptions.*.
I've heard different opinions on whether application-domain exceptions should inherit from related system exceptions. My opinion is that they should, because it's more descriptive and it's reasonable for catch statements that catch the upper type to also catch your type when you've deemed it behaviourally equivalent. You have added such a supertype for FileCreationException (which I think is fine) but no such supertype for the others. I suggest:
public class FileFormatException extends IOException {
// ...
public class InsufficientFundsException extends UnsupportedOperationException 
// ...
public class NoTransactionsException extends UnsupportedOperationException {
// ...

lastFreeID being static is dangerous - it's non-re-entrant. Either it should be an instance member, or if you need some kind of database management class, put it there. You're also using lastFreeID in a non-thread-safe manner; a race condition can occur at e.g. copyOfLastFreeId.
You're using some checked exceptions. That's fine-ish, though depending on who you ask they can be considered problematic. My personal opinion is that they're over-verbose and force a kind of boilerplate at the interface of checked APIs that doesn't offer value.
It's not a wonderful idea to write a replaceTransactionsWithFileTransactions. You should just throw the object away and construct a new one rather than re-initialising in place.
FileFormatException is a little strange of a name when matched with !Files.isReadable(filePath) - readable status doesn't seem like a "format".
At some point in the future you may be able to replace filePath.toString().endsWith with a built-in.
Avoid mutation-within-expression as seen here: (line = fileReader.readLine()) != null.
For long concatenation expressions like that in Transaction.toString, prefer "".formatted.
In start(), consider making a map of command strings to description-command objects.
enterTheDate should be using built-in datetime parsing rather than a split on a hyphen.
It's not a good idea to call transaction.toString() - which you've written yourself! - only to perform string substitution on it. Write a purpose-built serialisation method on transaction that produces the correct string on the first pass.

UnsupportedOperationException is the wrong superclass for the exceptions. It is intended to be thrown from methods that are defined as optional in an interface and are not implemented in the concrete class. I would rather create a common application specific exception class to act as a parent for these exceptions.
